# Problem with concatenation of 2 files in python

Tags: python, file, concatenation

I want to append two ASCII files (e.g. `F1_Jan_01.txt` and `F1_jan_01.txt` including in directories `d01`, `d02` respectively) in one file. In fact, I have two directories in where I have files for each category (`F1`,`F2`,`F3`), month and day (1 to 7) and I want to append the files with the same name locating in the two different directories. So, I wrote the following code in Python.

```
import pandas as pd

maindir1="/home/d01/"
maindir2="/home/d02/"
outdir="/home/final/"

pol=[ "F1","F2","F3" ]

month=["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]

for iis,ipol in enumerate(pol):
    for jjs,imonth in enumerate(month):
        for kk in range(1,7,1):
            df1 = pd.read_csv(maindir1+str(ipol)+"_"+str(imonth)+"_0"+str(kk)+".txt", sep="\t")
            df2 = pd.read_csv(maindir2+str(ipol)+"_"+str(imonth)+"_0"+str(kk)+".txt", sep="\t")
            df = pd.concat([ df1, df2 ], ignore_index=True)
            df.to_csv(outdir+str(ipol)+"_"+str(imonth)+"_0"+str(kk)+".txt",sep="\t",index=False)
```

The problem is that in the final output, when it appends the second file, it does not write its first line. For example, the first file (in `d01`) has 100000 lines and the second one (in `d02`), 50000. So, in the final output writes the first 100000 lines correctly and then it appends the 49000 lines of the second file excluding its first line.

Do I have to define anything else in the code?

Comment: If literally all you're doing is concatenating files, you don't need Pandas to do it!

Comment: try calling pd.read_csv(..... , header=None)

Comment: why not just read both files classically as 2 strings then output `read_str1 + read_str2` into the output file?

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol I tried adding header=None and it writes the file correct but it also adds a line as header in the output.

Comment: then when you call `df.to_csv` you also include `header=False`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using Pandas, here's the equivalent code. (Dry-coded, YMMV.)

```
maindir1 = "/home/d01/"
maindir2 = "/home/d02/"
outdir = "/home/final/"

pols = ["F1", "F2", "F3"]
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

for ipol in pols:
    for imonth in months:
        for kk in range(1, 7):
            template_args = {"ipol": ipol, "imonth": imonth, "kk": kk}
            filename = "{ipol}_{imonth}_0{kk}.txt".format(ipol=ipol, imonth=imonth, kk=kk)
            out_name = os.path.join(outdir, filename)
            in_names = [os.path.join(maindir1, filename), os.path.join(maindir2, filename)]
            with open(out_name, "w") as out_file:
                for in_name in in_names:
                    with open(in_name, "r") as in_file:
                        out_file.write(in_file.read())
```

Comment: I like how you also fixed the terrible inline string concat. But what's up with your template args? Also; since python 3.7 you can just do `filename = f"{ipol}_{imonth}_0{kk}.txt"` without `.format()` which is really cool.

Comment: Most people don't have Python 3.7 yet and I don't want to confuse them with a feature that doesn't work.